# Ajuda com testes no django

Tags: django, testes

Estou problemas com alguns testes(*pytest*) no *django* e queria se saber se alguém já passou por isso, tenho o seguinte:

```
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from recipes import views
from tests.TestBase.Recipe_TestBase import Recipe_Test_Base


class RecipeViewsTest(Recipe_Test_Base):
```

quando eu faço para `RecipeViewsTest` herde de `Recipe_Test_Base` os meu testes simplesmente para de funcionar corretamente, por exemplo eu faço com que um teste falhe, mas quando eu vou rodar os testes eles simplesmente passam sem apontar nenhum erro mais quando eu simplesmente apago a linha
`from tests.TestBase.Recipe_TestBase import Recipe_Test_Base` e faço com que `RecipeViewsTest(Recipe_Test_Base)` herde de `TestCase` ele começa a funcionar normalmente
Alguém ai já passou por isso antes ?
Como posso resolver isso ?

Obs: `class RecipeViewsTest(Recipe_Test_Base):` esse `Recipe` está em uma outra pasta e sim ele está herdando de `TestCase`

```
from django.test import TestCase
from recipes.models import Category, Recipe, User


class Recipe_Test_Base(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:

        return super().setUp()

...
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá! Parece que você está tendo problemas com seus testes no Django quando herda de `Recipe_Test_Base` em vez de `TestCase`. Aqui estão algumas coisas que você pode verificar:

1. **Método setUp**: Verifique se o método `setUp` na sua classe base `Recipe_Test_Base` está configurando corretamente o ambiente para seus testes. Se `Recipe_Test_Base` está herdando de `TestCase`, então você deve chamar `super().setUp()` no início do seu método `setUp` para garantir que a configuração do `TestCase` seja executada. Vejo que você já está fazendo isso, o que é ótimo!
2. **Outros métodos na classe base**: Se `Recipe_Test_Base` tem outros métodos que estão sobrescrevendo os métodos do `TestCase` (como `tearDown`, `setUpTestData`, etc.), eles podem estar interferindo na execução dos seus testes. Verifique se esses métodos estão funcionando como esperado.
3. **Ordem de herança**: Em Python, a ordem de herança pode afetar o comportamento da sua classe. Se `RecipeViewsTest` está herdando de outras classes além de `Recipe_Test_Base`, a ordem dessas classes na declaração de herança pode ser importante.
4. **Estado persistente**: Verifique se não há estado persistente entre os testes que possa estar causando esse comportamento. Cada teste deve ser capaz de ser executado de forma independente, sem depender do estado de outros testes.

Espero que isso ajude! Se você ainda estiver tendo problemas, por favor, forneça mais detalhes sobre o que `Recipe_Test_Base` e seus testes estão fazendo, e eu ficarei feliz em ajudar mais. Boa sorte!